# `bad-setting (Reason: Unit nftables.service has a bad unit file...` when add `/etc/systemd/system` conf to nftables

Tags: ubuntu, debian, systemd, systemctl, nftables

System is debian 10 with nftables.
I plan to make `nftalbes` auto restart when failed,script as below:

```
cat << EOF >> /etc/systemd/system/nftables.service.d/override.conf
[Service]
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=1s
EOF

systemctl daemon-reload
```

Output shows `bad-setting`:

```
systemctl status nftables.service

nftables.service - nftables
   Loaded: bad-setting (Reason: Unit nftables.service has a bad unit file settin
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/nftables.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: active (exited) since Sat 2021-07-24 18:57:51; 1h 13min ago
     Docs: man:nft(8)
           http://wiki.nftables.org
           man:nft(8)
           http://wiki.nftables.org
 Main PID: 2145 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 0B
   CGroup: /system.slice/nftables.service
```

Where is the problem?